# Getting error in using expected_conditions in python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have been using python and selenium for automation and here is the error I am getting frequently.

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'An invalid or illegal string was specified'
```

I am not sure what is wrong. This error occurs in the following line of my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a:contains(Sign In)"))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `a:contains(Sign in)` is not valid CSS.

If you want to do CSS, `a[href*='Sign In']` might do the trick, but it looks like you're clicking on a link, so the best solution is to do `By.LINK_TEXT,"Sign In"`

Comment: Yes, I see a very obvious mistake of not including the quotes on Sign In but I would disagree that the CSS is not valid. I checked it again and its correct. I still want your suggestion. Do you see anything wrong in my expected_conditions syntax? I hope that is not posing a problem for me... Please suggest!

Comment: Oh. I just looked it up, and contains() is valid CSS.  I've just never used it before, and it looks similar to the XPath syntax.  Go right ahead!

Comment: :) Its fine but what about my other question? Do you see anything wrong in the expected_conditions syntax that I have written?

Comment: Actually, the `contains()` function is officially deprecated in CSS, and is not supported by many browsers; so that might be your problem. Can you replace the CSS locator with something else, for example an equivalent xpath locator?

Comment: Praveen, the "An invalid or illegal string was specified" specifically tells you that the string you passed in was invalid CSS.  If you post the element you are trying to select, I can give you a better selector.  However, I would recommend trying the two I posted above.